# Pivottable: summarize multiple columns with similar data

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am creating pivot tables to summarize survey response data in an excel file.

Part of the data shows answers to *"How important is x to you?"* questions:

```
| Subject A | Subject B | Subject C | Subject D | Subject E |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Very      | Not at all| A little  | Very      | A little  |
| Not at all| Not at all| Very      | N/A       | Very      |
| Not at all| Not at all| Very      | Very      | N/A       |
| Very      | Not at all| Not at all| Very      | A little  |
| N/A       | Not at all| Very      | Very      | A little  |
```

In my pivot table, I would like to summarize the number of occurrences for each answer per subject respectively:

```
             | Subject A | Subject B | Subject C | Subject D | Subject E |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Very       | 2         | 0         | 3         | 4         | 1         |
| A little   | 0         | 0         | 1         | 0         | 3         |
| Not at all | 2         | 5         | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| N/A        | 1         | 0         | 0         | 1         | 1         |
```

I have spent some time trying to find a way to do this, but to no avail. Google is not being particularly helpful either. Is this because pivot tables simply do not support this kind of summary, or do I simply need more coffee? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because I made a typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data first. Specifically what is described in [this article](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/firstnormalform.htm) about database normalization as "Eliminate duplicative columns from the same table".
Instead of having five answer columns (one for each subject) have each row represent *one* answer to *one* question by *one* subject.

```
| Question   | Subject   | Answer     |
---------------------------------------
| Question 1 | Subject A | Very       |
| Question 1 | Subject B | Not at all |
| Question 1 | Subject C | A little   |
| Question 1 | Subject D | Very       |
| Question 1 | Subject E | A little   |
| Question 2 | Subject A | Not at all |
| Question 2 | Subject B | Not at all |
| Question 2 | Subject C | Very       |
| Question 2 | Subject D | N/A        |
| Question 2 | Subject E | Very       |
| Question 3 | Subject A | Not at all |
| Question 3 | Subject B | Not at all |
| Question 3 | Subject C | Very       |
| Question 3 | Subject D | Very       |
| Question 3 | Subject E | N/A        |
| Question 4 | Subject A | Very       |
| Question 4 | Subject B | Not at all |
| Question 4 | Subject C | Not at all |
| Question 4 | Subject D | Very       |
| Question 4 | Subject E | A little   |
| Question 5 | Subject A | N/A        |
| Question 5 | Subject B | Not at all |
| Question 5 | Subject C | Very       |
| Question 5 | Subject D | Very       |
| Question 5 | Subject E | A little   |
```

With a pivot table set up like the following you should get the desired result.

```
Column Labels: Subject
Row Labels:    Answer
Values:        Count of Question
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column on the left with `=Row()` copied down to suit. Unpivot (eg [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-flatten)). Delete left-hand column and pivot with `Column` for COLUMNS, `Value` for ROWS and Count of Value for Σ VALUES.